# is there a way to put javascript and css in the wigwam editor in expression engine?

Tags: wygwam, javascript

I'm trying to put this [slider](http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com) (scroll halfway down the page) into my site, which is built on expression engine using the wigwam editor.

i have the javascript saved here http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/slider.js but when i link to it under "source" in the editor the javascript doesn't load.

this is how i am linking it:

```
<script src="{path="http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/slider.js"}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and here is the Javascript (which works fine on non-ee sites)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("header.image").hide();
    $("header.image").find("img").load(function(){
        $(this).closest("header.image").show(5000);
    });
});
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

is not needs in path here

```
<script src="http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

p.s. EE is not parsed tags in entries w/o special add-ons